# Adjoint group of Lie Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I am self-studying Lie Algebras and Lie groups. In various sources, I came across the notion of the adjoint group of a given Lie Algebra. For example, the adjoint group of the Lie Algebra $sl_n$ is $PSL_n$. What I do not understand is how we can find the adjoint group of any Lie Algebra. Also, is this correspondence one to one?

Comment: Definition [here](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Adjoint_group) What correspondence are you referring to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a Lie algebra with Lie group $G$. The adjoint group of $G$ is the image of the adjoint representation $\mathrm{Ad}:G \to \mathrm{Aut}(\mathfrak{g})$. In other words it is every element of $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathfrak{g})$ that can be written as conjugation by an element of $G$. If we assume the field we are working over has characteristic $0$ then this doesn't depend on the choice of $G$ and so we can call this the adjoint group of $\mathfrak{g}$.

In general, we can think of this as the simply connected group associated with $\mathfrak{g}$ quotiented out by its whole centre (and you can use this to construct them). Moreover, for semisimple $\mathfrak{g}$ the adjoint group is just the connected component of the identity in $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathfrak{g})$.

The [wikipedia page on Simple Lie groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Lie_group#List) for the most part* lists the adjoint groups for simple Lie algebras in the "other names" column.

*The "others" table is a little vague

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Do you have any reference where it is proven that the adjoint group is the associated group with $g$ quotient out by the centre?

Comment: For a connected Lie group the kernel of the adjoint rep is precisely the centre of the group. So the image of the adjoint rep must be isomorphic to $G/Z(G)$.